# mysql-haskell no invoke of Right case of try function

Tags: mysql, haskell, servant

I am writing simple server with servant and mysql-haskell package where I invoke some insert query, this part of code:

```
...
    result <- try $ M.query conn ("insert into `user` (`email`,`name`,`date_joined`) values (?, ?, NOW());") [M.One $ M.MySQLText "1@mail.ru", M.One $ M.MySQLText "username"]
    
    case result of
          Right (defs,is) -> do 
                        putStrLn "No exception occurred"
                        print =<< Streams.toList is 
          Left e  -> putStrLn ("Caught exception: " ++ show (e :: M.ERRException))
...
```

Problem is that if I send request to insert new user, i see that it inserted in db, but there is no Right brunch invorked - i don't see "No exception occurred" in console and my client don't recieve response (just hanging) but as I said server provide real insertion to db (I see new row created) so it looks like it stucked in **M.query or try** function without invoking Rigth brunch..

Interesting that on second query with duplicate request it invoke the "Left" branch and I see

```
"Caught exception: ERRException (ERR {errCode = 1062, errState = "23000", errMsg = "Duplicate entry '1@mail.ru' for key 'uniq_site_email'"})
"
```

and client got the response without hanging.

I have:

```
GHCi, version 9.4.8
mysql  Ver 8.0.36 for Linux on x86_64
```

Why this happens and how to fix?

Comment: Probably an exception is being thrown, but its type is not `ERRException`. Try using `SomeException` (temporarily, while debugging -- don't stay with it in real code, as it may catch more than you intend) instead. And, by the way, you might also like `displayException` for a more human-readable error than what `show` will give you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found problem: need to use M.execute vs M.query

```
result <- try $ M.execute conn ("insert into `user` (`email`,`name`,`date_joined`) values (?, ?, NOW());") [M.One $ M.MySQLText "1@mail.ru", M.One $ M.MySQLText "username"]
```

It would be nice to add some error in lib for this case.